# Object doesn't support property or method 'assign' when using redux-logger with `useBuiltIns: 'usage'`

Tags: babeljs, redux-logger

I have this `babel.config.js` configuration:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache.forever();
  return {
    presets: [
      [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
        },
      ],
      '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', 'lodash'],
  };
};
```

As you see, I'm using `useBuiltIns: 'usage'`. But I need to support e.g. IE11, that does not have `Object.assign`.

There's one library that is using this `Object.assign` in their dist js: `redux-logger`. And apparently `babel` is not transpiling their dist js and I get runtime error that assign is not defined.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'

Interesting is that I see `Object.assign` polyfill in the bundle. So it seems that redux-logger code is executed before polyfill is available.

How can I fix it?